# Square wave generator using RPi 2

Tags: pi-2, signal

I am completely new to this and I am not into programming. My requirement is to generate a 965Hz precise square wave. This frequency may need fine tweeking from 955Hz to 975Hz depending on other conditions. I want to know if this is achievable using RPi 2 or 3. I have 12 V supply available, which can be regulated down as required. The amplitude and current output of the square wave generated is not a big issue. I can use an op-amp stage to adjust it. If is possible to output standard TTL level it is good enough.
Generating this wave form is the only job. When the power is on, it has to start generating and continue to do so till it is switched off. I thought it is an overkill to use a quad core processor to do this job, but the size of the board, possibility to get the desired frequency, cost etc make it a very desirable.

Please advise me on what software I might need to learn to program, do I need any other accessories other than the basic Pi board etc.
Thank you,
Umesh

Comment: joan's answer is spot-on (of course), but something like this (non-Raspberry Pi-based)  [Low Frequency DDS Function Signal Generator Module](http://www.sainsmart.com/low-frequency-dds-function-signal-generator-module-sine-square-triangle-wave.html "Low Frequency DDS Function Signal Generator Module") might do the job more economically.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a square wave in quite a few ways.  The simplest and probably the best is to use one of the clocks or the PWM peripheral.

Have a look at my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library.

From the command line http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#HC will generate a clock at a particular frequency.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#HP will do the same using the PWM peripheral.

You can make the same calls from C or Python.

Both use a granularity of 1 Hz to set the frequency.  If you need a better frequency resolution you'll have to adapt the code.

A Pi Zero, B+, or A+ will do just a good a job.

Comment: I am a C programmer myself, but for a new learner to accomplish this task, I think Python would be simpler to pickup.